# Manually publish messages to dead-letter queue?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Why would someone want to do that? I have to unit-test exception handling mechanism in our application.

I presumed that dead letter queue is literally azure service bus queue, where I could publish messages using `QueueClient`

```
string dlQ = @"sb://**.servicebus.windows.net/**/Subscriptions/DefaultSubscription/$DeadLetterQueue";
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
NamespaceManager _namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

QueueDescription qd = _namespaceManager.GetQueue(dataPromotionDLQ);
var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "DefaultSubscription/$DeadLetterQueue");
BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage("Message to PublishToDLQ");
try
{
    queueClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

But I get `MessagingEntityNotFoundException`. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You would never want to publish directly to a dead letter queue. It's where poisoned messages that can't be processed are placed.

There are two ways of placing messages onto the dead letter queue. The service bus itself dead-letters messages that have exceeded the maximum number of delivery attempts. You can also explicitly dead-letter a message that you have received using the DeadLetter() method.

Comment: I feel like the first sentence in this answer is directly ignoring the first paragraph in the question. "You would never want to publish directly to a dead letter queue" -- uh, yes, you would, if you're writing an automated test specifically to test handling of DLQ messages. That being, you know, what this entire question is about. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Create your messages with a very short TTL via the *BrokeredMessage.TimeToLive* property.

The Subscription must have `EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration` set to true.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I tried a TimeToLive as small as `TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)`, and still the Azure Function consumer processed it before it deadlettered. This is on a topic/subscription specifically for testing, so I will instead change the consumer to call `BrokeredMessage.DeadLetter()`.

Comment: Oops, no, my consumer does not violate properties of physics. For this solution to work the Subscription must have `EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration` set to true, which mine did not.

Comment: @Johann the setting is in the answer

Comment: Yes, because I added it.

Comment: Messages will not be moved to dead letter all of a sudden, as a separate asynchronous garbage collection is run on the service side and it moves the message periodically. When you Peek() the message, it is available to you, but when you Receive() the message, the garbage collection program is forced to run first and then you don't get "about to move to dead-letter" messages which I guess is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Though late here, adding to the answers of @Mikee and @Ben Morris may help someone. You can make use of @Mike's suggestion of making use of `message.DeadLetter()` or `message.DeadLetterAsync()` to dead-letter a message. Another suggestion can be to set very less or 0 second `TimeToLive` to move the messages to Dead letter.

After you perform any of these and try to view the messages in the Active end queue, you may still find that message is available sometimes (Which you are currently facing). The reason is that the messages that are dead-lettered due to `TTLExpiredException`, `HeaderSizeExceeded` or any system defined Errors, or manually Dead-Lettered messages like `DeadLetter()` methods are cleaned up by an asynchronous **"garbage collection"** program periodically. This doesn't occur immediately which we expect it to.

When you perform `Peek` operation, you can still see that the message is in the Active queue. You have to wait for the garbage collector to run or you can perform a `Receive` operation which forces the garbage collector to run first, thereby moving the messages to dead-letter before retrieval is done.